# Adding the result of an array in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I tried to make this algorithm: random draw between 0 and 1(tir).si tir '<'pred then Xestime2= 1 else Xestime2=0. I wish apply this algorithm in df ['X3'] but I had 0 in all the values ​​of X3 columns. Which explains thats i have an error in my code. 
My coding:

```
df = pd.read_csv(FNAME3, header=None)
print df[:15]
df['X2'] = df['X1'].round()
print df[:15]
s = StringIO()
df.to_csv("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Nouveau dossier (2)/Resultats2.csv", header=None, index=False)
#print(s.getvalue())

##########################################""""""""
for row in df['X1']:
    x = np.random.randint(0,2,10)
    for row1 in x:
        if row1 < row:
            df['X3']=0
        else:
            df['X3']=1
        #print df[:15]
df.to_csv("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Nouveau dossier (2)/Resultats2.csv", header=None, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged this pandas, I'll use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', header=None)

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   0         1
0  0  0.487130
1  0  0.248932
2  0  0.248932
3  1  0.405285
4  1  0.405285
5  1  0.405285
6  1  0.405285
```

Then you can just [round](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) the column (to the nearest 1):

```
In [3]: df[2] = df[1].round()

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   0         1  2
0  0  0.487130  0
1  0  0.248932  0
2  0  0.248932  0
3  1  0.405285  0
4  1  0.405285  0
5  1  0.405285  0
6  1  0.405285  0
```

*If any values were over a half, they'd be rounded to 1.*

Since you asked about sending this to StringIO, it's the same as you would with a file:

```
In [11]: s = StringIO()

In [12]: df.to_csv(s, header=None, index=False)
# alternatively write to file with df.to_csv('foo.csv', header=None, index=False)

In [13]: print(s.getvalue())
0.0,0.4871303471776849,0.0
0.0,0.2489319061991417,0.0
0.0,0.2489319061991417,0.0
1.0,0.4052854182229446,0.0
1.0,0.4052854182229446,0.0
1.0,0.4052854182229446,0.0
1.0,0.4052854182229446,0.0
```

Comment: I would like to add the results of Xestime in my file Results.csv. So I did a test on the values ​​of the second column that I called pred. In fact Xestime is 0 if pred <= 0.5 else Xestime=1

Comment: You have to rewrite the entire file, you can't just append to each line. e.g. df.to_csv('foo.csv')

Comment: yes but how can i do that because i would recuperate the results of Xestime? I checked  that when i made shape(my_data2), i had 30389 but when i made shape(Xestime), i had (), I don't know how can i use the results of my Xestime, which is in the loop (0,1...)

Comment: Andy, finaly I want to have a table with the results of x, pred and Xestime which is in the loop(look at the code above).The values ​​of x and pred are in the files results.csv

Comment: My final table should be like what Philip found.

Comment: updated :) used StringIO since you said you were interested in that, but file is the same

Comment: How?? I tried to update my code but i had an error!!(look at the code below).

Comment: I understand your code but when I try to apply it to my code it does not work!!

Comment: your column names are 'X0' and 'X1' (did you import from Excel?) So use df['X1'].round()

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `genfromtxt` if you're using `pandas`. `read_csv` is much more flexible.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from pandas import read_csv

sio = StringIO('''0.000000000000000000e+00,4.871303471776848859e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00,2.489319061991416837e-01
0.000000000000000000e+00,2.489319061991416837e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,4.052854182229445601e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,4.052854182229445601e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,4.052854182229445601e-01
1.000000000000000000e+00,4.052854182229445601e-01''')

df = read_csv(sio, header=None, index_col=None)
df['Xestime'] = (df[1] > 0.5).astype(int)
df.to_csv('foo_with_Xestime.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

`cat foo_with_Xestime.csv`:

```
0.0,0.4871303471776849,0
0.0,0.2489319061991417,0
0.0,0.2489319061991417,0
1.0,0.4052854182229446,0
1.0,0.4052854182229446,0
1.0,0.4052854182229446,0
1.0,0.4052854182229446,0
```

Comment: I tried to apply what you made but i have an error!! My coding

Comment: How can I put the contents of my file Results.csv in StringIO?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new file. If you read input data without errors (FNAME3 is a 2-column matrix) and the dimensions match (Xestime has exactly as many rows as FNAME3), than your

`NEW_MATRIX=np.column_stack((FNAME3, Xestime))`

solution should work. However, the third column will not get written into the file, but into the NEW_MATRIX variable. You have to write this to a new file and you're done:

```
np.savetxt('foo2.csv',NEW_MATRIX)
```

By the way, you overwrite your Xestime variable in each loop inside the if conditions. Try Xestime.append(5) to add a new item to the list instead of assigning an integer to the variable.

Comment: I tried your command but also i had an error when i made, NEW_MATRIX=np.column_stack((FNAME3, Xestime)). I had fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.string_